# Memory leaks not detected in XCode (C++)

Tags: c++, xcode, memory-leaks

I just started an OSX project on XCode and I noticed that my leaks are not being detected in the leaks instrument:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{
    int* foo = new int[10];
    foo = NULL;
    sleep(60);
    return 0;
}
```

[screenshot of instrument](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lVQqw.png)

I've never used the leaks tool before and I feel like I am missing something very obvious here. Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the name of the tool?

Comment: I am using the XCode Leaks Check Instrument. You can see it in the screenshot :)